# Is it possible to allow FileReference.save() via an ExternalInterface call?

Tags: javascript, flash, security

In an `onClick` listener in JavaScript I call a Flash method via `ExternalInterface` that attempts to present a file save dialog. However:

```
Error: Error #2176: Certain actions, such as those that display a pop-up window, may only be invoked upon user interaction, for example by a mouse click or button press.
    at flash.net::FileReference/_save()
    at flash.net::FileReference/save()
    at <my code>
    at Function/http://adobe.com/AS3/2006/builtin::apply()
    at flash.external::ExternalInterface$/_callIn()
    at Function/<anonymous>()
```

Is there any way to get this to work? Perhaps there's a security policy I can set, or have the user approve? I don't want to have to implement the whole button in Flash.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Unfortunately, it is not possible to call `FileReference.save()` or `FileReference.browse()` via `ExternalInterface`, even in response to some user interaction in the browser. These functions are only allowed in response to a direct user interaction event in the Flash Player itself. These security restrictions were added in Flash Player 10. You can read more about them [here](http://www.leebrimelow.com/flash-player-10-filereference-changes/).

Therefore, you are forced to either use a button directly in the Flash movie. Alternatively, you could try placing a hidden Flash button over the HTML button to catch the mouse click.